Where is the Bottleneck for multiple requests using Whisper on Nvidia A100
I want to use Whisper-Large-v3 (Speech-to-Text) for a real-time application. However, I want to process several requests at the same time. My Whisper instance runs on an Nvidia A100 with 80GB VRAM.
In principle, I would assume that I could process many requests at the same time, but that the KV matrices can probably only be accessed again once the first request has been processed. So it processes the requests sequentially, so to speak.
Then I used Gunicorn to start my application with several workers so that 2 independent Whisper instances are loaded.
Now I can process up to 2 requests at the same time, because every instance has his own attention weights. If I load more instances, e.g. 4 Whisper instances, I can still process a maximum of 2 requests at the same time and wait 2 more requests until the others are finished.
My question now consists of the contents, where the bottleneck is and whether someone has a more optimized implementation idea, how I can use the card for the inference more effectively. After all, there is enough VRAM.
Implementation method:

Transformers library + Pytorch
Attention: Flash Attention 2 or SDPA (both deliver pretty much the same results for short audios)
Pytorch backend

If anyone has tips for a faster inference or can simply enlighten me technically where the bottleneck is, that would be good.
My guess:
Pytorch backend is blocking contiguous memory blocks for the output and attention matrices, which is why I can't access unused matrices to process more requests in parallel. Since the VRAM is too large for me to have a problem with the high bandwidth memory, I assume that the matrices are loaded into the SRAM, which is not large enough to handle multiple requests at the same time?
Constructive feedback and discussion please.
UPDATE: 04.06.24
Thank you very much. These keywords have helped me in the search and with the batching or summarizing of audios in a dataset makes the inference much faster.
Nevertheless, I would like to build a real-time application and would like to know whether it is possible to do a kind of pipelining in addition to the batching in order to calculate in parallel on the graphics card.
My following test code looks like this:

I build the whisper instance


import torch
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers.utils import is_flash_attn_2_available
import time
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

pipe = pipeline(
    "automatic-speech-recognition",
    model="openai/whisper-large-v3", # from huggingface
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,  
    device="cuda:0",  
)



The main function starts a for-loop which starts an generator() to collect the audio files which are incoming.


# Define a generator
def data_generator():
    folder_path =  r'C:\Users\audios'
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        audio = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        yield audio

def main():
    for out in pipe(inputs=data_generator(), batch_size=8 ,return_timestamps=False, 
        generate_kwargs={"language": "en", "task": "transcribe"}):
        print(out)



If i do so, I can batch 8 audios at the "same" time. But in real-time application maybe i have the request sequentially but dont want to wait for some audios to finish before i can start the next transcription with the pipeline.

Is there a better way than sequentially call the pipe() function?

GPUs are designed to process batches of inputs. If you have unbatched requests coming in, the GPU will only process a single request at a time. You need to batch requests before sending them to the GPU. Send your requests to a queue, and have your GPU workers pull batches from the queue rather than single requests

https://huggingface.co/docs/text-generation-inference/en/index

Thank you. It helps a lot. I found new solutions with batching multiple files in a dataset.
